# Authenticate as root to view a folder?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, root, browser, authentication

Is there a way to setup nautilus so that when my user attempts to view a folder owned / locked by root, it asks for the root password?

Kind of like running a nautilus browser using sudo, from the terminal.

Comment: I wish the standard behavior was like that!

Comment: And then it should color the background of the folder to remind you that you are in root territory and can damage things.  And color the root-owned folders, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the »open as administrator« option in Nautilus gone?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78116/where-is-the-open-as-administrator-option-in-nautilus-gone)

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start at look for nautilus scripts here.

http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/cat-executing.php

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/a/128935/5032

Answer (score 0):

Install gksu nautilus-gksu libgksu2-0 for nautilus to right click and open as administrator.

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> copy and paste this:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu nautilus-gksu libgksu2-0
```

once it installs

then `nautilus -q`

now you have right-click properties for admin

**edit:** This used to work for 11.04 however please see this link [Where is the »open as administrator« option in Nautilus gone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78116/where-is-the-open-as-administrator-option-in-nautilus-gone)

The first answer explains the workarounds.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.  `E: Unable to locate package nautilus-gksu`