# 12.04 open folder as root

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the »open as administrator« option in Nautilus gone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78116/where-is-the-open-as-administrator-option-in-nautilus-gone)

To open a folder as root in the nautilus you just had to install `nautilus-gksu` from the Ubuntu repository. This nautilus extension adds an option to the nautilus called "Open as adminstrator". It does what it claims to do. After I updated Ubuntu I can't find the package anymore. It's removed from the software center. I really like this nautilus extension. How do I get this option on 12.04?