# Open file or application as root from GUI

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, sudo, gui, root

Is it possible to open a file or application as root from the GUI?

My ideal would be right-clicking on a file or an application and seeing an "Open as Root" choice in the context menu, after which I was asked for my root password.

Somewhat related to this is the ability to allow, for example, a save to take place where originally you had not opened the application as root (e.g., modifying a .conf file in /etc)

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78116/where-is-the-open-as-administrator-option-in-nautilus-gone

Comment: as far as it concerns an application, locked to the launcher, you might find what you are looking for here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I open a folder as root?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124023/how-do-i-open-a-folder-as-root)

Answer (score 10):

To run GUI applications with elevated permissions, you can use the `gksu` command:

You can check to see if it's installed with `which gksu` and if so it will output the path to the command. If not you can install it with the command `sudo apt-get gksu`

```
$ gksu nautilus           # browse files as root
$ gksu gedit /etc/fstab   # edit file as root
```

This command is a frontend to the `su` and `sudo` commands, designed for running graphical programs, so it is used the same way as them. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksu) for more information.

Comment: Can this method be scripted in some way that it consequentially be inserted into context menus?

Comment: @chrsmrrtt I don't know. It may be possible.

Comment: please note that gksu is no longer installed per default in Ubuntu >= 13.04 - but it is still available in the repos.

Answer (score 0):

> You should **never** use normal sudo to start graphical applications
>   as root. Using sudo with graphical apps has the potential to corrupt
>   your environment by  allowing root to take ownership of and/or change
>   permissions on critical  files that you must own. The forums
>   frequently see panicked requests  for help from users who can no
>   longer log in after running graphical  applications under sudo.
>
> Please note that many websites and old threads advise the use of gksu.
>   However, such search results are obsolete. gksudo has not been updated
>   for years and is not even available in Bionic (18.04) and higher. gksu
>   has been replaced by pkexec, but even pkexec is being deprecated by
>   the mainline Ubuntu developers. They have taken  the position that
>   file manipulation and editing under root should be  restricted to the
>   command line.
>
> We can only surmise what the motives were behind this decision:
>   perhaps  there are just too many users who run into problems running
>   graphical  apps as root. In any case, running graphical apps as root
>   now requires  workarounds and additional steps.
>
> #### Flavour-specific workarounds
>
> There are a number of flavour-specific options for running graphical
>   applications as root:
>
> 1. You can use pkexec on those flavours that support this option. As of 18.04, only Xubuntu supports this option by default, as shown in
>      the following examples:
>
>    ```
>    pkexec thunar  
>    pkexec mousepad /etc/fstab
>    ```
> 2. By default, Kubuntu allows easy access to a root file manager: **KDE Launcher → Computer → Root-Dolphin**
>
>    From there: (**→ edit file**) will open up a root instance of Kate.
> 3. Mainline
>
>    Ubuntu and Gnome use Nautilus as their file manager. Any flavor running Nautilus will allow you to install the package nautilus-admin
>      which will add two python extensions to Nautilus. These extensions add
>      options that allow root access: **Open as Administrator** and **Edit
>      as Administrator**
>
>    It is also possible to install the missing Policykit files for both Nautilus and Gedit. See [this
>      site](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/how-to-run-gedit-and-nautilus-as-root.html)
>      for instructions and links. A     knowledgeable user could build
>      further Policykit files for alternate     file managers and editors by
>      using the linked files as templates. They     are simple XML files
>      that can be edited with a standard text editor.
>
> #### General workarounds
>
> The following methods will work on all flavors:
>
> 1. Use the command line. Simple text editors like nano are quite easy to    learn. If you prefer a quasi-graphical file manager, install
>      Midnight    Commander. Both of these apps run under sudo with no
>      problems. Examples:
>
>    ```
>    sudo mc  
>    sudo nano /etc/fstab
>    ```
> 2. Notwithstanding the earlier warning, it is possible to use sudo with graphical apps provided you add the -H flag. This flag is
>      critical: it properly sets root to its own environment instead of
>      improperly inheriting the user's environment. Use of the -H flag is
>      mandatory. Failing to use this flag may corrupt critical system files
>      and prevent you from logging in.
>
>    With `sudo -H` almost any graphical app can be launched under root within any 'buntu flavor. This includes each flavor's default
>      graphical editor and file manager.
>
>    An appreciable danger with `sudo -H` is that the `-H` flag is easy to forget. And all it takes is one omission for the damage to be done.

<sub>**Source:** [Ubuntu documentation RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)</sub>

Comment: I wish this were a little more specific about what goes wrong with plain sudo... I've done it dozens of times, and survived; I just don't remember how. I think you just have to re-own a specific X.org-related file.