# Brightness Control not working Acer Aspire e1-531 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I installed on my Aspire E1-531 Xubuntu 14.04 and after the installation my brightness control is not working. I know this problem from Ubuntu 12.04.
There I could change the grub but in 14.04 it's not working because the don't accept `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` - the answer is:

```
sudo: gedit: command not found
```

any ideas what i could do? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install gedit first with:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Ideally though, you should use [`gksudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362021/open-file-or-application-as-root-from-gui) or similar to run GUI stuff as root so bits of your home directory don't accidentally end up being owned by root. You can use a command line editor such as `nano` instead:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

To use it simply edit stuff, then save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exit with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. You may need to install it first with `sudo apt-get install nano`.

After any apply changes, you should be able them by running `sudo update-grub` and rebooting.