# Error opening Ubuntu root file

Tags: permissions, root

Today I want to open the root file that I got into this problem

Does anyone know what to do?

Screen Shot : 
[image: Root File]

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-add-open-as-rootadministrator-to-context-menu/

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: `/root` is usually always only accesable by the `root` user. You can run `ls -la /` to confirm that. The folder (not file btw) `root` should have the permissions `drwx------` and owner `root root` meaning only the user `root` has permissions; others have not even the permissions to show the content. In order to access the content you should do it in the terminal(e.g. after running `sudo -i` to kind of "login as root") since it is highly unrecommendable to open the file browser with `root` permissions. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root is the user `root`'s home folder. Normal users should not have permissions on this directory - and there is nothing inside this folder of interest.

Ubuntu does not use the root user, but the directory is required to comply with file systems standards.

Furthermore, Linux uses filesystem access control. A normal user does not have access to everything.

You may have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362021/open-file-or-application-as-root-from-gui) Q&A for information on how to become the super user of the system if you need it. In general, be careful with files that require root access for editing or viewing. Changing them may break your system.