# Nautilus - file does not open as admin

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I run an ubuntu server and I installed nautilus in gnome to get the possibility to open a textfile as administrator. But when I right-click on the file and select "open as administrator" I get prompted with the admin password - when I enter it and click "ok", nothing happens... Do I have to select a standard textedit or something like this?

Additionally is it possible to run the terminal in a window in the gnome gui?

Thanks!

Comment: @Pilot6 The OP is already use it, his problem that nothnig change not in the presence of `open as administrator`

Comment: How did you know nothing change?! did you try to save the file in some protected dir and been asked for a password?

Comment: @Pilot6 Don't care, have a nice time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` package, to open virtual terminal in GUI.

About nautlius, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/78143/316028) I found answer which should help you